# How to perform a depth first search given an array of edges

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

For a class assignment I have found myself with a set of edges in a graph. I'm wondering if it is possible to perform a DFS on this graph without translating the data to a set of vertices.

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: You need a way to access all edges which go out from a given vertex. Otherwise you can't perform a DFS since you always need to take the next edge which starts at the given vertex.

Comment: @Zabuza. I didn't think there was any more information that I needed to give since it's a rather high level question. I had the same thought regarding accessing all edges but wasn't sure of it's validity or quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `DFS` and also for `BFS` you need a data-structure which provides access to edges by their **source**.

So a method like this is needed:

```
Edge getOutgoingEdge(source)
```

If you just have a set of all edges you won't be able to fetch the next edge to process after following your first edge. Let's assume you traversed an edge `a -> b` then the next edge you follow must be of kind `b -> c`. Thus you need some kind of structure which provides edges per source:

```
getOutgoingEdge(b)
```

If you don't have such, you **need to construct it before** by traversing all edges in your set and creating some kind of `Map` `source -> {e edge | alpha(e) = source}` (where `alpha(e)` denotes the source of an edge).

You can construct this map **on-fly**, i.e. stopping once you found the next edge for your `DFS` but the complexity will still be `O(|E|)`.